# Ebay - get Seller Feedbacks using REST api

Tags: ebay-api

How can i get seller feedbacks (reviews) using REST API on ebay?
I have only found this documentation "GetFeedback" to get them here https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/GetFeedback.html

Comment: Have you been able to find a solution in the meantime? Even 1.5 years later, I still can't find any documentation on how this is supposed to work via the RESTful API.

Comment: @user3731513 no I finally had to use it GetFeedbackRequest XML :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to sign up with a developer account first - there is a 24 hour security delay before these will work so that's your first action. Once that's done you need to go through setting up authentication, which is detailed here: https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/static/authorization_guide_landing.html

NB, the eBay API documentation is long and rambling, and not well written. It is a headache but it does work I assure you!

Comment: yes this is clear but how can i get seller feedbacks (reviews) using REST API? i can't find a REST method to do it

Comment: @Altravista I'm looking for that information right now.